# .NET Framework 4.8 не поддерживается этой операционной системой

Tags: .net, windows, windows-8

При установке .NET 4.8 выходит такая ошибка. У меня WIndows 8, x64. 
 На сайте майкрософт пишет, что моя операционка поддерживает эту версию, но как не пытаюсь установить всегда выходит эта ошибка[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прошу помочь мне с решением этой проблемы, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Marco, только что посмотрел, нету там вашей операционной системы. Обновляйтесь либо до 8.1, либо до 10

Comment: `Поддержка Windows 8 корпорацией Microsoft прекращена 12 января 2016 года. ` https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8 Всё логично, поддержу @danilshik.